# Why associative array of R is called list and not map/dictionary

Tags: r, data-structures

I have recently started learning `R` language. I come from Java/Python background. One thing I found surprising is that `associative array` in `R` is called `List` and not something like `Map` or `Dictionary`.

I think that names like Map and Dictionary better convey the idea that data structure is associative array than list. Can you please let me know what is the background/reasoning behind this.

Comment: This kind of question is not a good fit for the technical Q&A style of StackOverflow. It isn't about a practical problem you're facing and is likely to be closed. You will find a more suitable audience for these sorts of questions on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 19, accepted):

S has a longer history than do either Java or Python. The terminology derives from LisP one of the first high level languages.

Furthermore, you can create what some people might call an associative array by using a named atomic vector:

```
 vec <- c(a=1,b=2,c=3)
 vec["b"]
 #b 
 #2
```

There are two sort of vectors: "recursive" and "atomic". Lists are of the first sort. Both can be indexed by "name" if there are keys assigned to the elements. However the term "name" in R strictly refers to symbols that exist in an environment that have object values. See `?as.name`. In R "names" or "symbols" are language objects that in code are not quoted, whereas character values are used to assign or extract value from data objects by keys.

Comment: +1 for LisP! as `List` Programming!

Comment: But what Lisp calls a list is actually a list (a singly linked list, to be precise). The Lisp variants that also offer associative containers don't call them lists (because they aren't).

Comment: You are ducking my point (and illustrating why this question was closed). S was around before either of the two languages cited as having better terminology. It's not that difficult to use S/R lists with car and cdr functions. `LL <- list(1,2,3); car <- function(x) {x[[1]]} ; cdr <- function(x){ x[-1]}`

Comment: "There are those who will tell you that LISP is an acronym for LISt Processor and others who insist that it stands for Lots of Infuriatingly Silly Parentheses." -- The Art of Lisp Programming

Comment: "S"? Do you mean "R"?

Comment: Yes S. R is a syntactic clone of S. I was pointing out that S (and by inheritance R) used named list and named vector structures before Python or Jave existed, so asking why S/R didn't follow Java/Python's lead is getting the history of computing languages backwards.

Answer (score 2):

A "Map" is a chart of the world. To find things on a map you have to scan in two dimensions. This is O(n^2). A "Dictionary" is a book of words in alphabetical order. To find a word in a dictionary you have to do a binary search. This is O(log n) performance.

So neither of those words, to me, accurately portray the structure nor the performance of an associative array...

Mathematically speaking an associative array is simply a function over a discrete range. So they should just be called functions. Double-square brackets are just a syntactic annoyance. Why can't we do:

```
z = list()
z("foo") = c(1,2,3)
print(z("foo")) # prints 1 2 3
print(z("bar")) # errors
```

- because R isn't like that.

Comment: "map" or "mapping" is sometimes used as a synonym for "function"

Comment: ...because mathematicians don't already have enough words to confuse us with.

Comment: A map from a c++ programmer's perspective is definitely not a 2d structure. "Maps are associative containers that store elements formed by a combination of a key value and a mapped value, following a specific order." -> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/